# OCaml graphics package

Tags: graphics, ocaml

I have installed OCaml on my xfce and now I want to do some graphics program.
The problem is that I don't know how I can install graphics.cma ( I think it's this file that I need but i'm not sure ).

I have research on Google and in This forum but I can't find it..

After little search, I see that i have graphics.cma and graphics.cmxa .

I found this with `ls $(ocamlc -where) | egrep cmx?a`

I don't know why but yet, my graphics function work at all.
Sorry for inconvenience.

Thanks for helping me guys.
Have a nice day

Comment: How did you install ocaml (opam, distro package, ... ), and what do you mean by "installing" graphics.cma ?

Comment: Hey, I have install ocaml like this : sudo apt-get install ocaml

I mean that I want to use graphics function like "Graphics.open_graph x ;;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest installing and using `ocamlfind` in order to not have to worry about library location:

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -package graphics -linkpkg  test.ml
```

will compile your file with the right files loaded.
You can also load the package in the toplevel using

```
#use "topfind";;
#require "graphics";;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have already installed the graphics module.

On Debian based systems the ocaml package is split into ocaml-base-nox and ocaml-base. The later contains the graphics module while the former is trimmed down.

The ocaml package is a meta package that depends on both of those and the description says (at the end):

```
This package contains everything needed to develop OCaml applications,
including the graphics libraries.
```

So you are all set to play with graphics. Juliens answere of installing ocamlfind is a good idea though as it makes using graphics and other modules easier.